# Find distribution function

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be random variable such that $$\Pr(X = 0) = 0.8 \\ \Pr(X = 1) = 0.1 \\ \forall x \in (0,1) f_X(x) = 0.1$$
Find distribution function $F_X(x)$.

I have no idea how solve it. Maybe I need some theory, but I don't know where should I search. I will grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using the *definition* of the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$. Recall that
$$F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x).$$
We will have to pay careful attention to the inequality sign: $\le x$ is not the same thing as $\lt x$.

First let $x\lt 0$. Then $\Pr(X\le x)=0$. There is no "stuff" to the left of $0$.

Next let $x=0$. Note that $\Pr(X\le 0)=\Pr(X=0)=0.8$. There is a "point mass" of $0.8$ at $x=0$.

More generally (and this includes the case previously dealt with), 
suppose  that $0\le x\lt 1$. The mass up to $x$ is the point mass at $0$, plus the contribution from the interval $(0,x]$. This contribution is $(0.1)(x-0)$.  Alternately, we could use the equivalent $\int_0^x (0.1)\,dt$.  Thus if $0\le x\lt 1$, then $F_X(x)=0.8+(0.1)x$.

Now let $x= 1$. Note that $\Pr(X\le 1)=0.8+\int_0^1 (0.1)\,dt +0.1=1$. More generally, if $x\ge 1$ then $F_X(x)=1$.

**Remark:** Intuition about "weights" is often more accurate than intuition about probabilities. What we have here is a point mass of $0.8$ at $x=0$, a point mass of $0.1$ at $x=1$, and a wire of density $0.1$ joining $0$ and $1$. Everywhere before $x=0$, and after $x=1$, we have "wire" of density $0$.

Then $F_X(x)$ is the total mass from "$-\infty$" all the way up to and including $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand. The next question is, if I have other random variable $Y$ which is very similar to $X$ (and they are independent), how can I compute $E(XY)$ and $Var(X+Y)$? I suppose that firstly I should compute $EX$. But how can I do it, if $F_X(x)$ is cumulative and discrete function?

Comment: The simplest way is to use what is technically called conditional expectation. With probability $0.8$, $X=0$. With probability $0.1$, it is $1$. With probability $0.1$, it is uniform in $(0,1)$, so has expectation $1/2$. Thus $E(X)=(0)(0.8)+(1)(0.1)+(1/2)(0.1)$. Use a similar technique to find $E(X^2)$, and then you will know $\text{Var}(X)$. In an additional comment, I will give an alternate derivation of the same thing.

Comment: (Cont.) Or else let $U$ be the random variable which is $1$ at $0$ and $0$ elsewhere. Let $V$ be the r.v. which is $1$ at $1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Finally, let $W$ be uniform on $(0,1)$. Then $X=(0.8)U+(0.1)V+(0.1)W$. Now use the linearity of expectation.